# Active Directory - Add Auxiliary Classes to Person

Tags: active-directory

I am setting up an testing environment with Active Directory.

I created some custom attributes in Active Directory Schema and an `Auxiliary Class` called `AdditionalHRInfo`.

I did try to add this auxiliary class to `person` class. However, it is not able to add it.

An alert box was shown with "The change was rejected by the schema master server.".

My question is:

1. Is it possible to add auxiliary classes to `person` class?
2. Where is the log file for Active Directory Schema?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After many tries, I found that, if there is a `mandatory attribute` in my auxiliary class, it is **NOT** able to add to `person` class.